# Connecting to Private Geth Blockchain network using MetaMask

Tags: private-blockchain, geth-debugging

I am new to Blockchain and  created a private geth network in Aws EC2.

I need to connect my metmask wallet to that network. From my metamask wallet , I am not able to see that network.

Kindly let me know what I have to do for the same. boot node and sealer node are running

Previously I have deployed a local network in local machine and it was visible as localhost:8545.

Answer (score 0):

Use this as a RPC Url  -> AWS Public key:8545

Example RPC URL - **http://3.6.100.33:8545/**